Is there an online pdf to the Shaar HaKollel of the Alter Rebbes reasoning to his sidur?
BH
I heard a book of the Alter Rebbe's reason for his rules and decisions on his sidur was printed called Shaar HaKollel is there a place where you can view it online?

It's available on HebrewBooks.org: https://hebrewbooks.org/16002
